# Conductance and Seeback coefficient calculations with tbtrans

Tags: siesta, electronic-transport

Like the title says, in TranSiesta I can easily calculate the transmission curves. I know that it is related to the conductance. However, how can I calculate the conductance with tbtrans?

Moreover, to calculate the Seeback coefficient, one should modify the T and extrapolate the value from -dV/dT. Can someone explain better how to perform calculations with gradients of temperature?

Comment: How did this go? Is there any update?